# Image improvement

Tags: windows, gratis, image-processing

I just stumbled across [Deep Image Prior](https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/deep-image-prior) and am extremely impressed by its capabilities. Please, do take a look

Not just artifact removal, which is excellent, but in-painting, where it can "recreate" pieces which have been cut out of an image, and also remove text printed over an image.

I have many thousands of photos & other images and wonder if there is a similar program which can handle most of the following:

- runs on Windows
- is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- can scan a directory tree, either offering all images side by side with a proposed improvement, or offering only those images which it thinks can be improved
- can improve low light photos
- can improve blurry photos
- can "in-paint" where I have used another program to remove some visually unappealing parts of an image
- I don't have so much need for removing print in front of images, but it doesn't hurt to have it
- obviously, it should retain the original while saving any improvement of which I approve (e.g my_pic.jpeg gets saved as my_pic_improved.jpeg)

The idea is for me to scan all of my images, one by one, fairly quickly, identifying candidates for improvement, and then improving them, whether by auto-improvement or manually.

I have some digital photos which I have been saving for decades against the day that it would be possible to retrieve something from them

Comment: That indeed looks interesting. If there're any cross-platforms, I'd like to have it for Linux :)

Comment: This looks like a brand-new research product, so a user-friendly shrink-wrapped version is still a while away. Your best bet for the time being is likely to build on their code yourself.